# How do I import one workspace into another in Synapse Analytics Workspace

Tags: azure-synapse

How do I import one workspace into another workspace in Synapse Analytics? For example, I would like to import dev synapse into qa synapse.

It should behave like Azure Data Factory does where you can Import and Export ARM template.

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunately, you cannot transfer an entire Azure Synapse Analytics workspace to another Azure Synapse Analytics workspace/subscription.

I would suggest you to vote up an idea submitted by another Azure customer.

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/307516-azure-synapse-analytics/suggestions/36256231-enable-support-for-cross-subscription-restore

[https://feedback.azure.com/forums/307516-azure-synapse-analytics/suggestions/40528870-connectivity-to-code-repositories-similar-to-data](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/307516-azure-synapse-analytics/suggestions/40528870-connectivity-to-code-repositories-similar-to-data+)

All of the feedback you share in these forums will be monitored and reviewed by the Microsoft engineering teams responsible for building Azure.

- Azure SQL scripts, Notebook can be imported/exported from Azure Synapse Studio.
- For pipelines, linked services you can download the support files and copy the JSON template and create a new pipeline using the same JSON template.
- You can also use Azure PowerShell modules for to import and export.

For more details, refer [Az.Synapse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.synapse/?view=azps-4.8.0)